# What is the image size and resolution I should prepare images for Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I'm putting some images into Codename One but they don't look nice. I'd like to ask some generic questions regarding using images with Codename One.

Say, if I have a splash screen which occupies the entire screen on portrait mode, what is the **image size** and **resolution** I should prepare the image file? That is, this is the big size and would fit on a large device without pixelation and automatically scales down on smaller devices (using Multi-images).

I guess once I get the advice on the image size and resolution, I can prepare images in their starting big size, and let it scale down proportionately to smaller devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are many devices out there with different screen sizes and DPI/PPI, you can't keep up with the biggest size and resolution. For instance, Samsung Galaxy S7 edge has a screen resolution of 1440 x 2560px while iPhone 7 plus has a 1080 x 1920px...generating images of these sizes will increase your app size tremendously.

As a personal preference, I keep my original image resolution at a maximum of 800 x 1280px  and I ignore `Very low`, `Low`, `560`, `2HD` and `4K` when I'm generating Multi-images.

`HD` will be used for any screen size above it while `Medium` is used for anything below it. Using this, I never noticed any pixelation on the real devices and I've tested on both devices I mentioned above.